# Long Column not spooling properly

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max column width in Oracle spool to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156527/max-column-width-in-oracle-spool-to-file)

I have a LONG column in a table. I want to spool the contents of this column into a spool file. I have written the below file and am running it. The problem is that only the first 81 characters of each line are written in the spool file. I have set the linesize as 100000 but still the problem persists. What changes do I need to make to get the f?

```
set head on
set linesize 100000
set pagesize 50000
set long 100000
set echo on
set trimspool on
set colsep ';'

SPOOL D:\DCN.SPL

SELECT long_col FROM table;


SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: I don't think `SPOOL` is standard SQL. Please add a suitable RDBMS tag.

Comment: @Orangecrush: You are welcome. I can't post that as an answer because your question should be closed as a duplicate and link-only answers are not allowed.